# what's it mean 'return;'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 tabs.on('click keydown', '.ui-icon-close', function(e) {
   if (e.type === 'keydown' && !(e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.SPACE)){
   return;
}
```

I have seem it couple time in jQuery book that expression 'return;'. Can anyone explains what exactly it means? Thanks

Comment: you realize that jquery is just a function library built on top of javascript? that's a plain jane javascript `return`, like any other javascript `return`, and does about the same thing as `return` in most any other programming language...

Comment: `return;` is the same as `return undefined;`.

Comment: so in this case, when the event click and keydown is caught, the callback function return undefined?  I guess the function returns the event object that contains the event target and type, but the expression of 'return;' just seem strange to me. It doesn't make sense if it returns undefined

Comment: @Dai Wang You're right, the return doesn't really have any effect in this situation. You could remove it.

Comment: Do you mean beyond what it says in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)?

Comment: @DaiWang Please mark the best answer as accepted to help future visitors to find the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is a keyword is JS that you can return a value from a function with that. It ends the function excution, and returns the value passed to it.

In some functions, there is no need to return a value, but `return` is still useful, because it can terminate the function. For example you want to ommit some parts of code, if some conditions exists, you can write something like this:

```
somecode1();
if(something)
    return;
somecode2();
```

so if `something` happens, function is terminated and `somecode2()` will not execute.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, it means to to stop running the current function and return to the calling function, without returning a variable or variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Return is what a function will give back to whatever is calling it. For example:

```
var total = sum(1+2);


function sum(a, b){
return a+b;
}
```

In this example the function "returns" the summation of a and b.

A function can return any type of object, like a string, integer ,array, etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: For simple JavaScript returns this is true, but a `return` in a jQuery function callback could mean a lot more than just "stop execution" or "here, have *x*".

Comment: hi, Bryant. I understand that, but I just get confused with 'return;' becuase I can't tell what exactly the function is returning.